# Laravel 5 eager loading, select column from eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I am trying to

```
1. select `DOS`,`name`,`fin`,`ins_type` from events table. 
2. site_name from sites table
3. client_name from clients table
```

but unable to access site_name, client_name column in select statement

```
->select('DOS','name','fin','ins_type')
```

How to add these columns `site.site_name`, `client.client_name` in above select statement.

Eloquent query is

```
 $events = Event::with([
                    'site'=>function($q){
                        $q->select('site_id','site_name','client_id');
                    },
                    'site.client'=>function($q2){
                        $q2->select('client_id','client_name');
                    }])
                ->select('DOS','name','fin','ins_type')
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$events = Event::with([
                'site'=>function($q){
                    $q->with(['client'=>function($qq){
                        $qq->select('client_id','client_name');
                    }])->select('site_id','site_name','client_id');
                }])
            ->select('DOS','name','fin','ins_type')
            ->get();
```

Comment: i tried this also. but its same as above. I want to include these two columns `site.site_name`, `client.client_name` with these selected columns  `select('DOS','name','fin','ins_type')` in master table `events`

Comment: without `select('DOS','name','fin','ins_type')`, i am able to access `site_name` and `client_name`

Comment: You have to select relationship fields also. If `site` belongs to an `event` by `id`, you have to select the `id` also from events. And also select for `site`, the `event_id` - in case you are using this standard schema.

Comment: Well, based on your query, I assumed that you have a relationship (hasOne, hasMany etc.) set between Event and Site, and Site and Client. If so, the result from the query should look like `Event(DOS, name, fin, ins_type, **site** =>(site_id, site_name, client_id, **client** =>(client_id, client_name))) `. Without a relationship defined in the Model, it certainly won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution from the comment section in [here](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/column-selection-in-eager-loading). It is possible to put the column selection in the model. So in your case, your Event model could be something like this.

```
public function site()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Site')->select('id', 'name', 'client_id');
}
```

Then, in your controller you simply call the function.

```
$events = Event::with('site')->get();
```

I haven't tried how this goes with the nested eager loading though.

Answer (score 0):

I myself got a little problem with these also until i discover that you need to add the foreign key to the select statement inside the "with" closure.

the column that relates "client" to "site" and "site" to "Event"